# Xamarin PCL Bluetooth can't see devices

Tags: android, ios, forms, xamarin, bluetooth

I'm trying to using xamarin for do a test app.
This app must search bluetooth devices, view them into a list and connect to them for read or write data.
I choose xamarin Portable Class Library for my project.

I see a lots of examples but I can't see devices in my list.

I try [Monkey Robotics](https://github.com/xamarin/Monkey.Robotics) (project 'Robocontroller' and project 'BLE') but scanning I can't see devices!
Robocontroller:

```
05-30 15:14:21.048 D/Mono    (11792): [0x7f6946d000] worker starting
05-30 15:14:21.063 I/mono-stdout(11792): BluetoothLEManager: Scan timeout has elapsed.
BluetoothLEManager: Scan timeout has elapsed.
05-30 15:14:21.065 D/BluetoothAdapter(11792): stopLeScan()
05-30 15:14:21.067 D/BluetoothAdapter(11792): 622203304: getState(). Returning 12
```

BLE:

```
Adapter: Starting a scan for devices.
05-30 15:23:53.549 D/BluetoothAdapter(17688): startLeScan(): null
05-30 15:23:53.647 D/BluetoothLeScanner(17688): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
adapter.StartScanningForDevices(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)
05-30 15:23:53.755 I/mono-stdout(17688): adapter.StartScanningForDevices(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)
[0:] adapter.StartScanningForDevices(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)
05-30 15:23:53.768 I/Choreographer(17688): Skipped 152 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #7
05-30 15:24:03.718 D/Mono    (17688): [0xba2bcf40] worker starting
BluetoothLEManager: Scan timeout has elapsed.
05-30 15:24:03.801 I/mono-stdout(17688): BluetoothLEManager: Scan timeout has elapsed.
05-30 15:24:03.808 D/BluetoothAdapter(17688): stopLeScan()
```

I tryed others projects like 'estimotes', 'xamarin BLE' (the one with old code that redirect to Monkey.Robotics) and 'BluetoothLEExplorer'.
I'm using latest version of xamarin with vs2015 pro.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have **LE**-based devices in the scan range vs. classic bluetooth devices? Not all devices are LE or are enabled for both profiles....

Comment: Yes, I use for debug asus koa1 and other device that must be found are: lumia 950xl, mac mini, other android phone. I try to change the asus with other smartphone but same issue

Comment: Do you see these devices, when you use a 3rd party app like "BLE Scanner"? Have you tried our BLE Plugin? :D https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le use the prerelease of 1.0 if you want.

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe I try it but not work. Output: Adapter: Scan failed with code ApplicationRegistrationFailed | Adapter: Scan timeout has elapsed. | Adapter: Stopping the scan for devices. | Adapter >= 21: Stopping the scan for devices. | D/BluetoothLeScanner(29598): could not find callback wrapper. Thanks for your help

Comment: What is your Android version?

Comment: @Nfear 5.0 on asus k01A

Comment: I used the wrong method, I had read that the ble could see devices with normal bluetooth but it's not true. I have tried other projects like [blacksun.xamarinforms](https://github.com/angelcalvasp/Blacksun.XamForms) running on Android but are not implemented for iOS, someone has to suggest me other samples with iOS?
Thanks

Comment: @mene do you have any success with it ? i need to use simple bluetooth( not BLE specifically) functionality in PCL. Is it even possible to write common code in PCL for Android and IOS

Comment: @Basit ZIa I read about it: BLE can't see normal phone bluetooth.. I have sucessly see another device using normal bluetooth, but pcl project never include the  3OS, always 2. Thanks. have a good day

Answer (score 0):

Using BLE you can't see another bluetooth devices (like android phone), must be a ble device.